# Java error "Method optString(i) is undefined for JASONArray"

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to to parse JSONArray to a java array through this function:

```
public String[] readJSONArray (JSONArray jsonArr){
        String[] arr = new String[jsonArr.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = jsonArr.optString(i);
        }
    }
```

Error "Method optString(i) is undefined for the type JSONArray" is returned on the last line. I am using JSON simple. Where does my mistake lie? I would like to use rather an array than a list.

Comment: Do you really mean `JASONArray`?

Comment: What is the full package of your `JSONArray` class ?

Comment: you are not returning anything from this method

Comment: post your json string here.

Comment: Which part of the error message is confusing you? [`org.json.simple.JSONArray`](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/target/apidocs/org/json/simple/JsonArray.html) does not have a method named `optString()`. Why do you think it does? Perhaps you should try [`getString(int index)`](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/target/apidocs/org/json/simple/JsonArray.html#getString-int-) instead.

Comment: Since `JSONArray` extends `ArrayList<Object>`, you should just call `jsonArr.toArray(new String[jsonArr.size()])` to get the `String[]`.

Comment: Uff, spelling fixed (I hope), sorry for that.

The imports are these:
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
.
I know out about the return but that should not be cause of the error, is that right?

Andreas: I will try that right away, thanks a lot! I was basing my code on another example here in the forums. It used .optString(i) to access the JSON array.

Comment: @Faire : `optString` comes from another `JSONArray` class, e.g `oracle.adfmf.json.JSONArray` https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf220/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: Ok, solution suggested by Andreas worked very well, thank you! I see where my mistake was now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code based on solution by Andreas:

```
public String[] readJSONArray (JSONArray jsonArr){
        String[] arr = (String[]) jsonArr.toArray(new String[jsonArr.size()]);
        return arr;
        }
```

Thanks a lot!